# What is a good AWS solution (DB, ETL, Batch Job) to store large historical trading data (with daily refresh) for machine learning analysis?

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, mysql-python

I want to build a machine learning system with large amount of historical trading data for machine learning purpose (Python program).

Trading company has an API to grab their historical data and real time data. Data volume is about 100G for historical data and about 200M for daily data.

Trading data is typical time series data like price, name, region, timeline, etc. The format of data could be retrieved as large files or stored in relational DB.

So my question is, what is the best way to store these data on AWS and what'sthe best way to add new data everyday (like through a cron job, or ETL job)? Possible solutions include storing them in relational database like Or NoSQL databases like DynamoDB or Redis, or store the data in a file system and read by Python program directly. I just need to find a solution to persist the data in AWS so multiple team can grab the data for research.

Also, since it's a research project, I don't want to spend too much time on exploring new systems or emerging technologies. I know there are Time Series Databases like InfluxDB or new Amazon Timestream. Considering the learning curve and deadline requirement, I don't incline to learn and use them for now.

I'm familiar with MySQL. If really needed, i can pick up NoSQL, like Redis/DynamoDB.

Any advice? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use AWS EMR, then the simplest solution is probably just to run a daily job that dumps data into a file in S3. However, if you want to use something a little more SQL-ey, you could load everything into Redshift.

If your goal is to make it available in some form to other people, then you should definitely put the data in S3. AWS has ETL and data migration tools that can move data from S3 to a variety of destinations, so the other people will not be restricted in their use of the data just because of it being stored in S3.

On top of that, S3 is the cheapest (warm) storage option available in AWS, and for all practical purposes, its throughout is unlimited. If you store the data in a SQL database, you significantly limit the rate at which the data can be retrieved. If you store the data in a NoSQL database, you may be able to support more traffic (maybe) but it will be at significant cost.

Just to further illustrate my point, I recently did an experiment to test certain properties of one of the S3 APIs, and part of my experiment involved uploading ~100GB of data to S3 from an EC2 instance. I was able to upload all of that data in just a few minutes, and it cost next to nothing.

The only thing you need to decide is the format of your data files. You should talk to some of the other people and find out if Json, CSV, or something else is preferred.

As for adding new data, I would set up a lambda function that is triggered by a CloudWatch event. The lambda function can get the data from your data source and put it into S3. The CloudWatch event trigger is cron based, so it’s easy enough to switch between hourly, daily, or whatever frequency meets your needs.